# Java App Suddenly Stop A Few Days (8-10) After

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

i created java standalone app.This app sends a mobile and events to every each 5 seconds with one thread(Main) and application stop Event Request Starting... or Mobile Request Starting... line in below request method.How can i fix this error.

I cant get no throw message.

I can handle this when the database connection and the network connection are 
 disconnected.

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Connection connection = openConnection();
        try {
            mobileEventList = null;
            if (connection != null) {
                mobileEventList = Dao.getMobileEvents(connection);
            }
            if (failEventFlag) {
                if (failMobileEventList != null && failMobileEventList.size() > 0) {
                    mobileEventList.addAll(failMobileEventList);
                    LOGGER.info("Fail Event , failMobileEventList Size->" + mobileEventList.size());
                }
            }

            mobileList = null;
            if (connection != null) {
                mobileList = Dao.getMobiles(username, connection);
            }
            int responseEvent = setLogEvents(endPointEvent);
            int responseMobile = setLogMobile(endPointMobile);
            if (mobileEventList != null && mobileList != null && responseEvent != 0 && responseMobile != 0) {
                if (connection != null) {
                    Dao.updateHeartBeat(appName, connection);
                    LOGGER.info("HeartBeat updated.");
                }
            }
            closeConnection(connection);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOGGER.info("Gecen milisaniye->" + ((endTime - startTime)));
        if (((endTime - startTime)) < this.repeatTime) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(this.repeatTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each getEvents and getMobiles send Request ->

```
private static int request(String params, String endPoint, boolean isEvent) {

    if (isEvent) {
        LOGGER.info(" Event Request Starting...");
    } else {
        LOGGER.info(" Mobile Request Starting...");
    }

    DataOutputStream wr = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    URL url = null;
    int responseCode = 0;
    try {
        url = new URL(endPoint);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=" + StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        conn.connect();
        wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(params);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        isFailEvent(responseCode, isEvent);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        isFailEvent(responseCode, isEvent);
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (wr != null) {
                wr.close();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        params = null;
    }

    if (isEvent) {
        LOGGER.info(" Event Request End  Http Code : " + responseCode + " End Point: " + endPoint);
    } else {
        LOGGER.info(" Mobile Request End  Http Code : " + responseCode + " End Point: " + endPoint);
    }

    return responseCode;
}
```

Comment: Please do the `closeConnection(connection)` in the `finally` block

Comment: Yes you are right but I do not think it will cause this fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we expect the post to work when we send the request and then return a response to us for the responseCode with setDoOutput (true) in the HTTPUrlConnection method.Sometimes responseTime last 30sec so setReadTimeOut(0) default url conenction. Sometimes doesnt get responsecode and suspect program. so we must add setReadTimeout parameter  like this **conn.setReadTimeout(40000);**

```
 conn.getResponseCode();// stay there
```

Comment: please tell us what you think about it